# Performance metrics on Amazon Managed Blockchain

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, amazon-managed-blockchain

I have setup Amazon Managed Blockchain using Hyperledger fabric.

I am trying to send some transactions to the blockchain.

How can I view **performance for the blockchain** and other related metrics?

Comment: Might be relevant: [Using Peer Node Metrics - Amazon Managed Blockchain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-peer-node-metrics.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Using Peer Node Metrics - Amazon Managed Blockchain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-peer-node-metrics.html):

> You can use **peer node metrics** to track that activity and health of peer nodes that belong to your Amazon Managed Blockchain member. You can use the Managed Blockchain console to view the metrics for a peer node. Managed Blockchain also reports metrics to **Amazon CloudWatch**. You can use CloudWatch to set up dashboards, receive alarms, and view log files for peer node metrics.

Metrics include:

- **Transactions:** The number of transactions that a peer node receives per minute.
- **CPUUtilization(%):** The percentage of total CPU capacity used on the peer node's Managed Blockchain instance at any given instant.
- **MemoryUtilization(%):** The percentage of total available memory used on the peer node's Managed Blockchain instance at any given instant.